# How to create a DAO/Service layer with Grizzly/JAX-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs, grizzly

I'm using Grizzly instead of Glassfish for this JAX-RS application.  I'm new to this technology so I've been googling around a lot and can't seem to find a good outline for how to setup a Service/DAO layer in my applicatiion.

Below is the working prototype that I have.

**My Resource**

```
@Path("/helloworld")
@Stateless
public class MyResource {

    @EJB //DOESN'T WORK - how do I map this service to this resource?
    WorkflowService workflowService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String TestRequest() {
        Workflow workflow = new Workflow();
        workflow.setName("test");

        workflowService.save(workflow);

        return "Workflow ID:";
    }
}
```

**My Dao**

```
public class WorkflowDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "unit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public int save(Workflow workflow) {
        entityManager.persist(workflow);
        return workflow.getId();
    }
}
```

**My Service**

```
@Stateless
public class WorkflowService {

    @EJB //I know EJB is probably wrong here, not sure what else to do yet.
    WorkflowDao workflowDao;

    public int save(Workflow workflow) {
        int id = workflowDao.save(workflow);
        return id;
    }
}
```

**Update** - I realize EJB won't work with my setup.  So my question is, what does?  How do I make the service accessible in my resource?

**-------------- Final/Working Code --------------**

**Resource**

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class MyResource {

    WorkflowService workflowService;

    public MyResource() {
        workflowService = new WorkflowService();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String TestRequest() {
        Workflow workflow = new Workflow();
        workflow.setName("test");

        workflowService.save(workflow);

        return "Workflow ID:";
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public class WorkflowService {

    WorkflowDao workflowDao;

    public WorkflowService() {
        workflowDao = new WorkflowDao();
    }

    public int save(Workflow workflow) {
        int id = workflowDao.save(workflow);
        return id;
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
@Singleton
public class WorkflowDao {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public int save(Workflow workflow) {
        getEntityManager().persist(workflow);
        return workflow.getId();
    }

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        return em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I can answer your question fully. But I can tell you that `@EJB`is part of JavaEE 6 which can only be run in a WebApplication Server.

Grizzly is not one of them (compared to Glassfish which is one).

**EDIT**

If you want to have dependency injection you can use the Spring framework.

Comment: To answer your updated question, I've added Spring in my previous answer.

Also, you can choose to instantiate your services in your JAXRS implementation, and make your DAO a singleton.

Comment: When they're instantiated in my JAXRS implement can you provide a code example?  For instance, I know I can do `workflowservice = new WorkflowService();`, but how will I map the `EntityManager` to the DAO?  I'll add `@Singleton` to my DAO

Comment: You can just use the singleton pattern to make your DAO a singleton ;) see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Eager_initialization

Comment: Can you provide any insight on how I should map the `EntityManager`?

Comment: You can use an `EntityManagerFactory`, although I cannot remember the exact syntax for using it.